# How can I code dynamic sets in GAMS environment?

Tags: dynamic, constraints, equation, equation-solving, gams-math

I want to code a constraint in GAMS environment but I can't. The constraint that I want to code is seen in the image. In this constraint, `x(i,m,t)` is a binary variable but `x(i,m,t)` binary varible is changed as `x(i,m,d)` and as seen in the image shown, the number `d` depends on `t-p(i)+1`. In `t-p(i)+1`, `p(i)` is a parameter and `t` is a set of times. In this equaiton, I know what the equation wants to calculate but I can't code it in GAMS.
How can I code this equation in GAMS environment? Thank you.

[Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1naYy.png)

Comment: I think you forgot to add your image.

Comment: Hi Jasper, I did not forget the image. I added it as named "Constraint" just below my comment.

Comment: Please just add the image into your question. It helps to be able to see it together with your question, plus remotely hosted images might be taken down leaving this question without some important context.